# Need help understanding the output of a code

Tags: c#, output

So i ran the following code through an online C# compiler and the result was d=23 x.i=22.

```
class X
{
    delegate int D(ref int i);
    private int i=10;
    int m1(ref int i)
    {
        return i++;
    }

    int m2(ref int i)
    {
        return i*=2;
    }

    int m3(ref int i)
    {
        return i--;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X x = new X();
        D d1 = new D(x.m1), d2 = new D(x.m2), d3 = new D(x.m3);
        D d = d1+d2; 
        d += d1; 
        d += d3-d1;
        System.Console.WriteLine("d=" + d(ref x.i) + " x.i=" + x.i);
    }
}
```

However,when i go through the code myself i never get this for the output.Its probably because i'm not understanding something right. So i will tell you now how i tried solving this and if somebody could point out the mistake i'm making,it would be much appreciated.

So first we have a constructor for x and i is equal to 10. Then from what i understood about delegate,its like a pointer/reference to the class and d1=10, and afterwards x.i=11 because of i++. Then d2=22 and x.i=22 because of m2 method.Then d3=22 and i is then 21. Afterwards d=d1+d2 is 10+22 which is 32,then d+=d1 is d=10+32 which is 42 and finally d+=d3-d1 is d=42+(22-10)=52 and i in the end is 21.

So can anybody point out where i'm making a mistake,what is it that i don't understand how it works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question isn't readable. Please format it properly.

Comment: Can you please be more specific what i should format better? Is it the code lines? Or maybe how i tried solving this? I really don't know what isn't readable.

Comment: Indent the code in your question with 4 spaces, this will format it as code.

Comment: Is there a single part of it that you don't understand? There's so many layers inside layers in this question that it seems to be more a puzzle than a concrete programming question.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Okey,will do it

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: I guess he/she is confused about the `delegate`.

Comment: I'm confused as well because he has generated a gordian knot of delegates and methods using ref. I question the purpose of this code because nobody in their right mind would write code like this. If it's to learn how things work then a much much simpler example would be much more beneficial.

Comment: Syntax error `d += d3–d1`!

Comment: The syntax error is because it's not the minus sign, it's a hyphen, some text editor has chosen a different symbol.

Comment: @HusseinGolshani i changed it now to a minus

Comment: I'll make a guess that the confusion comes from this line: `d += d3-d1;`, this does not remove `d1` from `d`, it only adds `d3`, because `d3-d1=d3` since `d3` does not contain `d1` to begin with. So `d` has this sequence: `d1, d2, d1, d3`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen This was a question on one exam,its not supposed to be practical,just to test how well we understand the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods will be called in this order, interleaved with the values of i.

```
i = 10
m1 -> returns 10, then increases i to 11
i = 11
m2 -> multiplies i up to 22, returns 22
i = 22
m1 -> returns 22, then increases i up to 23
i = 23
m3 -> returns 23, then decreases i down to 22
i = 22
```

So that's why your output is `d=23, i=22`.

The sequence of your delegate additions, with the resulting delegate chain, is as follows:

```
D d = d1 + d2;
// d = d1, d2
d += d1;
// d = d1, d2, d1
d += d3-d1;
// d = d1, d2, d1, d3
```

Note that `d3` does not contain `d1`, so `d3-d1` is equal to `d3`, that means that the following two lines are equivalent in results:

```
d += d3;
d += d3-d1;
```

---

Strictly speaking, m1 does not "return 10, **then** increases i to 11", instead it does the following sequence of operations:

1. Read `i`, having the current value 10
2. Increase `i`, up to 11
3. Return the value it read in step 1, which was `10`

Answer (score 0):

the code is run in the following order:

```
int result;

// d1 + d2
result = x.m1(ref x.i);
// now x.i = 11 and result = 10
result = x.m2(ref x.i);
// now x.i = 22 and result = 22

// d1
result = x.m1(ref x.i);
// now x.i = 23 and result = 22

// d3 - d1 which is d3 because d3 does not contains d1
result = x.m3(ref x.i);
// now x.i = 22 and result = 23
```